# Spring Form (with file field) validation

Tags: java, spring, image, forms, validation

I try to validate form that looks like:

[image: html form]

My controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value = { "/new", "/{id}/update" }, method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String processForm(Model model,
        @Valid @ModelAttribute EventFormDto eventForm, BindingResult validationResult) {
...
```

And data class:

```
//@ImageOrImageFileName(image = "image", imageFileName = "imageFileName")
public class EventFormDto {

    @NotEmpty(message="{valid.notempty}")
    private String title;

    @NotEmpty(message="{valid.notempty}")
    private String detail;

    @ImageFile
    private MultipartFile image;
    //private String imageFileName;

    @NotNull(message="{valid.notempty}")
    @DateTimeFormat(pattern="dd/MM/YYYY HH:mm")
    private DateTime startDate;

    ...
}
```

And my problem in case when image field pass validation but any other field has validation error. On the server side is already possible to save the image so as not to send it again. Ant at data class probably I ned new field called imageFileName. So image validation should see at both image and image-name fields.

Can someone show me how to write validation for this case.

Comment: You can validate image file extension and filename through regular expression. Here is link: http://www.mkyong.com/regular-expressions/how-to-validate-image-file-extension-with-regular-expression/

Comment: I use something like.What I should to do if image passed validation rules but title field is empty? Ask user for resubmit image?

Comment: Yes you should ask user to upload image again if title is not matching. That's how other sites also work.

Comment: Why I can't save valid image and pass in form saved-on-server-image-name.some string. And user will be able write only title or other not valid fields.

Comment: Yes you can do that. But how many such images you will store and for how long? if you are using cache to store, then its fine since users may leave in between. So you need to think about space/memory required to store images and later delete if they are not required.